# Palindrome Function with FOR loop

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I am having a problem with a palindrome function.
This is my function :

```
function palindrome(str) {

  var newStr= str.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '').toLowerCase().split("");

  for(var i=0; i < (newStr.length)/2; i++){ 
    if(newStr[i] == newStr[newStr.length-i-1]){ 
      return true; 
    } else 
      return false; 
  }

} palindrome("almostomla");
```

It goes well with every word except with this one "almostomla" and others like it, for example: "amariorama", it is incorrect. Why does it happen?

Comment: check `palinidrome("aqua")`. Your code only compares the first and last character. It returns too early.

Comment: Also, `almostomla` and `amariorama` are not actually a palindrome, I think.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you are using return statement inside a loop, which gets executed just after checking only the first and last element of the array and then function returns true of false, which is wrong.

Also, note : almostomla and amariorama are not pallindrome
Its easy to check pallindrome using reverse() method as following:

```
    function palindrome(s) {
       var reverseString = s.split("").reverse().join("");
       if(s==reverseString)
          console.log("palindrome");
       else
          console.log("not palindrome");
    }
    palindrome("almostomla");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is failing because you return on the first iteration of your loop. You should return only at the end - or if the check fails you can return right away.

```
function palindrome(str) {

  var newStr= str.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '').toLowerCase().split("");

  for(var i=0; i < (newStr.length)/2; i++){ 
    if(newStr[i] == newStr[newStr.length-i-1]){ 
      //return true;
    } else 
      return false; 
  }
  return true;
}
```

This can be refactored to remove the `else`

```
function palindrome(str) {

  var newStr= str.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '').toLowerCase().split("");

  for(var i=0; i < (newStr.length)/2; i++){ 
    if(newStr[i] !== newStr[newStr.length-i-1]){ 
      return false;
    } 
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes , now i see the problem. Thank you so much mate

Answer (score 0):

A palindrome is a word, phrase, number, or other sequence of characters which reads the same backward as forward, such as madam or racecar. Sentence-length palindromes may be written when allowances are made for adjustments to capital letters, punctuation, and word dividers, such as "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!", "Was it a car or a cat I saw?" or "No 'x' in Nixon".

In the above code you are only checking for the first and last character of string, you need to check for the entire string.

```
function palindrome(str) {

  var newStr= str.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '').toLowerCase().split("");

  for(var i=0; i < (newStr.length)/2; i++){ 
    if(newStr[i] !== newStr[newStr.length-i-1]){ 
      return false; 
    }  
  }
 return true;
}
```

this would be correct code.